# Always need to detect screen resolution after switching OS with KVM switch

Tags: windows-7, kvm-switch

I used to have Windows Vista with my same setup I currently have and I could switch between my Windows and Linux computer without problems.

Now since I upgraded to Windows 7, when I switch from my Linux back to my Windows (which is my main unit with 2 monitors) I have to always to go to screen resolution and detect for it to find the second monitor.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The KVM switch you have does not pass the correct EDID back to windows 7 system. 
Add an EDID emulator between win 7 system and the KVM will solve the issue.

Comment: wouldnt it be a software issuie and not a hardware issuie since it was working just fine before i switched to windows 7?

Comment: Yes, it is the OS/software issue. Windows 7, Windows 8 and other advanced OSs check the system's devices/ resources all the time.

Comment: if its a sofwatre issue, why do i need to buy a edid emulator?

Comment: @Willl: I think it could be that this EDID emulation can be done in software?